# $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k(k+1)^{\frac{1}{n}}}>n$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, combinatorics

I think the following question is true:

For each positive integer $n\geq 2$, prove

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k(k+1)^{\frac{1}{n}}}>n$$

I try using by induction on $n$, but I think this is not easy with induction.

Do you have any idea or comment for proving it?

So thanks for any comment and help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main term behaves like $k^{-\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)}$, hence it should not be difficult to tackle the problem through creative telescoping (section 1 [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxKdOVsjsuEwdjBEM1dpRkhMa2s/view)). If $a>b>0$ and $n\geq 1$ we have
$$ n(a-b)b^{n-1}\leq a^n-b^n \leq n(a-b)a^{n-1} \tag{1}$$
by simply considering the expansion of $\frac{a^n-b^n}{a-b}=a^{n-1}+\ldots+b^{n-1}$.
 If we pick $a$ as $\frac{1}{k^{1/n}}$ and $b$ as $\frac{1}{(k+1)^{1/n}}$ we get:

$$\small n\left(\frac{1}{k^{1/n}}-\frac{1}{(k+1)^{1/n}}\right)\frac{1}{(k+1)^{1-1/n}}\leq \frac{1}{k(k+1)}\leq n\left(\frac{1}{k^{1/n}}-\frac{1}{(k+1)^{1/n}}\right)\frac{1}{k^{1-1/n}}$$
from which:
$$ \frac{1}{k(k+1)^{1/n}}\geq n\left(\frac{1}{k^{1/n}}-\frac{1}{(k+1)^{1/n}}\right)\tag{2} $$
leading to the claim in a straightforward way:
$$ \sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{1}{k(k+1)^{1/n}}\geq n. $$

Answer (score 5):

This solution works for any real number $n\geq 1$.  Using [Bernoulli's Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality), we have 
$$
\begin{align}\frac{n}{k^{1/n}}-\frac{n}{(k+1)^{1/n}}&=\frac{n}{(k+1)^{1/n}}\,\left(\left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right)^{1/n}-1\right)
\\
&\leq\frac{n}{(k+1)^{1/n}}\,\Biggl(\left(1+\frac{1}{nk}\right)-1\Biggr)=\frac{1}{k(k+1)^{1/n}}\end{align}$$
for every positive integer $k$.  The equality holds iff $n=1$.

On the other hand, we can see that
$$\begin{align}
\frac{1}{k(k+1)^{1/n}}&<\frac{1}{k^{1+1/n}}=\frac{n}{k^{1/n}}\Biggl(\left(1+\frac{1}{nk}\right)-1\Biggr)
\\
&\leq\frac{n}{k^{1/n}}\Biggl(\left(1-\frac{1}{k}\right)^{-1/n}-1\Biggr)=\frac{n}{(k-1)^{1/n}}-\frac{n}{k^{1/n}}
\end{align}$$
for every integer $k\geq 2$.  This proves that
$$n\leq \sum_{k=1}^\infty\,\frac{1}{k(k+1)^{1/n}} <\frac{n+1}{2^{1/n}}<n+1-\ln(2)<n+\frac{1}{2}\,.$$
The left-hand side of the inequalities above becomes an equality if and only if $n=1$.  If $0<n<1$, we have a different bound:
$$\frac{n}{2^{1/n}}<\sum_{k=1}^\infty\,\frac{1}{k(k+1)^{1/n}}<n\,.$$

> Interestingly, a similar argument yields the inequality $$n-1<n-\ln(2)<\frac{n}{2^{1/n}}<\sum_{k=1}^\infty\,\frac{1}{k^{1/n}(k+1)}\leq n$$ for every real number $n\geq 1$.  The right-hand side of the inequalities above becomes an equality if and only if $n=1$.  If $0<n<1$, we have a different bound: $$\frac{n}{2^{1/n}}+\frac{1}{2}<\sum_{k=1}^\infty\,\frac{1}{k^{1/n}(k+1)}<n+\frac{1}{2}\,.$$

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as it gives the better estimates. It's also the only answer that actually solves the problem until now.

Comment: Thank you very much. your answer really interesting!

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

It doesn't completely prove the result, but a rough lower bound can be obtained by
$$\frac{1}{k(k+1)^{1/n}}\ge\frac{1}{(k+1)^{1+\frac{1}{n}}}\ge \int_{k+1}^{k+2}\frac{1}{x^{1+\frac{1}{n}}} d x$$

Comment: We do get $\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{(1+x)^{1+1/n}}\, d x = n$, so it seems pretty sharp.

Comment: @ThomasAhle Unfortunately we get $\int_2^\infty = \frac{n}{2^{1/n}}$

Comment: At least it leads to a better bound than $n-1$, as $$\frac{n}{2^{1/n}}>n-1$$ for every $n\geq 1$.

Answer (score 2):

Since $\zeta(s)>\dfrac{1}{s-1}$ for $s>1$ then
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k(k+1)^{\frac{1}{n}}}>\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(k+1)^{1+\frac{1}{n}}}=\zeta\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)-1>n-1$$

Comment: This solution doesn't yield the lower bound $n$, though.